# Using Constraint View with databinding causes error "Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. >

Tags: android, gradle

I'm a little new to android app development so forgive me in advance for being a newbie!  I've been fighting an issue that I can't find a resolution for on any boards.  I'm experiencing it in a larger project I'm working on but I've dumbed it down to the below test harness.  It seems to only occur when I combine databinding and constraint views.  Once I encounter the error even if I clear all of my constraints on the controls and rebuild them in a way that typically builds the error persists.  The only way out is to cntrl-z and redraw constraints in a way that will build or revert to a backup copy of the project. very odd. The effect I was going for with the text and button views was for them to be attached to each other more or less.

1) Create `New Project > Target API 19 4.4KitKat > Empty Activity`

2) Change app gradle to implementation `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1` (otherwise the RC01 makes design view of `ActivityMain.XML` in the IDE not work)

3) Add `dataBinding.enabled = true` to the app gradle

4) Wrap the Constraint View in `ActivityMain.xml` with `<layout></layout>` (this is to make databinding work)

5) In Design View of `ActivityMain.xml`, Drag a TextView and a Button on the screen

6) Constrain the TextView left to the parent left and the TextView top to the parent top

7) Constrain the Button top to the TextView Bottom, the button right to the parent right and the button left to the TextView left

7) Sync project with gradle files >> get error below

I've also provided the contents of `ActivityMain.xml` below.

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: duplicate attribute.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\justi\\AndroidStudioProjects\\MyApplication\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\activity_main.xml","position":{"startLine":10}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task `:app:mergeDebugResources`.

  > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
- Try:

Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output. Run with `--scan` to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
9 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 8 up-to-date

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Android Studio 3.1.3
Build #AI-173.4819257, built on June 4, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<layout` tag does not end. Also no need to add `xmlns:android` and `xmlns:app` two times.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: I think this gets me what I need.  Android Studio was taking it upon itself to insert the app and android code into the <layout> tag that I'd added to make databinding work.  it duplicated the same code that had auto-generated in the constraint view tag when the project was created.  The two were then in conflict.  Since Android was more or less randomly adding the additional code snippets it was really hard to determine what the cause of the errors was and led to the flaky behavior (gradle errors occuring then persisting after backing out most recent changes)

Comment: Remember data binding is still in beta mode, and not mature. So always build project after doing work on a layout.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the correct code. Only the `layout` end tag was missing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: yeah, i missed the </layout> on my paste into this post.  i have corrected the question above  still have the same behavior.

Comment: Try to remove     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"    from constraintlayout